# Create 'global' header and footer with react

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm not sure If I can accomplish with react what I have in mind. I read multiple introductions to react and feel that it should work. However, I would appreciate some reassurance by people familiar with react.

**What I want:**
Global header and footers, as they do not change on any of the pages I have. I could solve it with php... however I want to start with react and feel it would be fitting to solve it that way. An example of what I mean: [Global header and footer in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489341/global-header-and-footer-in-html) (that's basically the functionality I need from react)

My Footer contains certain divs and ULs. eg:

```
<div>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I feel that a component in react could be the footer/header. Is this doable or reasonable to try with react? Thank you!
(I don't necessarily wish for code examples but rather opinions if it would work out generally)

Comment: Yes, this is easily and simply accomplished with React. Since an opinion is all you want, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Thank you Ted. That's just what I need to now. All the rest I'm going to figure out by myself, I guess (hope) :D Worst case, I'm gonna ask again.

Comment: Hey @wftico, as per your need global header and footer components. you have to try this example [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter-n5zgxz)

Answer (score 4):

you can have one layout component

```
const Layout = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <header />
            { props.children }
            <footer />
        <>
    );
}
```

where <> is a fragment, header and footer can be components or whatever. Later you can use it like example abovce

```
<Layout>
    <div>Content goes here</div>
</Layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not put them in `App`, the parent to every component?

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <EntryPointComponentToPages />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or, if they're just unchanging HTML tags, you could put them in `index.js` surrounding your div that renders React:

```html
<body>
  <div>Header HTML here!</div>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <div>Footer HTML here!</div>
</body>
```

I'd base my decision on: does this seem like something React/JavaScript needs to or should handle? Is this code I plan to change often?

Answer (score 2):

There are different implementations to share Header/Footer all over your project components:

1- importing Header & Footer Component where you want to use them:

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            /** Content **/
            <Footer />
        <>
    );
}
```

2- Using Higher Order Components (HOC):

by importing header and footer once in a Layout HOC

`Layout.js`

```
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";

const withLayout = Page => {
  return () => (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Page />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default withLayout;
```

`HomePage.js`

```
import withLayout from "./Layout"
const HomePage = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            /** Content **/
        </div>
    );
}
export default withLayout(HomePage);
```

Note that Layout.js is not a `react` component, it's a wrapper function for react components where it embeds the header and footer components.